# Webscraping algorithm being blocked at network level

Tags: python, networking, web-scraping, vpn, ipconfig

I'm running a webscraping algorithm in Python (using BeautifulSoup) and I have potentially been blacklisted from one of the websites I visit:

As a matter of fact:

- I **cannot scrape pages on my main computer**, even though I use a fake User-Agent (identical to my browser) + VPN (VPN Gate from Tsukuba University)
- I **cannot scrape pages if I use my current network on another device**
- I **am able to scrape pages using another network** (phone hotspot, other WiFi, etc.)

I've read a bit about IP rotating but I don't know if it is the IP that has been blocked by the website (as I can access the website from my browser).
I've tried to /renew + /release my ipconfig as well

Thanks a lot

Comment: Obviously site owner thinks webscraping harms its business so your actions are illegal by his/her book. Do you ask for advice on how to become more experienced thief? Do you ask people to help you to harm other person/company? **my advice is:** use official API and pay for the usage. Site owner will be eager to provide you with support.

Comment: As you said : illegal by the website's book... Not illegal by law... It is private usage algorithm and I don't have the financial surface to start paying for various APIs. My question actually refers to a network / connection issue and I think it is fair to ask..